# If temperature is defined using length of mercury column, how is change in heat is proportional to it?

Tags: thermodynamics

Temperature is degree of hotness, but it has to be explicitly defined using a scale of temperature. When change in temperature is arbitrarily defined with the mercury column, (like Celsius scale before corrected) how is it exactly proportional to actual physical quantity of Change in Heat, that can be observed in calorimetric measurements?

Comment: I don't really follow the question. A fixed temperature change will require different amounts of heat energy depending on the substance, and a fixed change in heat energy will result in different temperature changes depending on the substance. That's exactly the role of C in the equation, it's the specific heat of the particular substance.

Comment: If there is no phase change, $\Delta Q=m C_p \Delta T$, where for a given mass and specific heat of a given substance, the quantity $m C_p$ is the proportionality "constant" that ties heat and temperature change together.  Could you be more specific on what you want to know, as I don't understand your ending question.

Comment: By substance I mean the thermometric liquid. Wikipedia says originally on celsius scale, change in temperature is conventionally defined as change in length of mercury column. How is it proportional to actual change in heat?

Comment: @DavidWhite I mean, before thermodynamics and ideal gas thermometer, people defined temperature with length of mercury column, arbitrarily. If it was an arbitrary number to make sense of hotness or coldness, what I don't understand is how is change heat proportional to it.

Comment: You seem to have a hidden assumption that a given change in temperature on a thermometer is proportional to heat absorbed or emitted by all substances.  If so, note that this is definitely not true, as the mass and specific heat capacity must both be considered in heat transfer calculations, as stated in my previous reply.

Comment: Temperature is degree of average kinetic energy of particle in particle ensemble. When thermometer liquid absorbs heat, it is stored as increased internal energy of liquid particles. Most stuff expands on higher internal energy levels. This is measured by specific thermal expansion, which is $60 \mu m/(m \cdot K)$ for [Mercury](http://elementsquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The thermodynamic temperature scale which allows this is called *degrees absolute*, or *degrees kelvin*. The fahrenheit and celsius scales were not designed with this goal in mind, but instead were defined to furnish temperature scales which were convenient for humans to use in everyday situations.

Comment: So, you mean ΔQ = mCΔT doesn't necessarily work for fahrenheit and celsius?

Comment: @Green_Peas, it works wherever the *delta T* appears, but for cases where T appears instead you must use kelvins.

Answer (score 0):

Mercury's volumetric thermal expansion coefficient is roughly constant over the relevant domain.

Given

$\Delta V = \beta \Delta T$ for some constant $\beta$

and

$\Delta V = A \Delta h$ for some constant cross-sectional area $A$, height $h$ in a pipette

and

$\Delta T \propto \Delta Q$ for a homogenous substance neglecting phase change (the mercury)

then if you put some mercury in a sealed near-vacuum pipette and draw 100 evenly spaced $\Delta h$ marks between the boiling point and freezing point of water,

$\Delta h \propto \Delta Q$

Note however that the relevant $Q$ is the internal energy *of the mercury*. The thermometer tells us nothing about the internal energy or change thereto of the sample whose temperature is being measured, it merely tells us the temperature of the sample by comparing it to a calibration mark of a known sample (the mercury) with which it is in thermal equilibrium.

Comment: I presume by ΔT you mean change in temperature in absolute scale. let me use 't' for temperatures on mercury thermometer. Say 2 bodies, one hot at t1 and other cold at t2 come in thermal contact and reach an equilibrium at t3. What bothers me most is it isnt obvious